# Why can't I adjust the backlight's brightness?

Tags: manjaro, intel-graphics, backlight

Lenovo Z500 series Intel graphic 4000 on Manjaro (latest, installed 2 days ago, fully updated)

I have a Lenovo laptop and I never had any problem under Linux Mint with the backlight... I installed Manjaro and I tried to raise the brightness a little (it was at 50%) and when I pressed the Brightness+ key on my keyboard, it set the brightness to 0 and now I'm stuck...

I tried following [this](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Reactivating_the_Backlight):
`xbacklight -inc 100` but doesn't work.

The GUI to adjust it doesn't work either.
I tried switching my linux kernel to 3.14, 3.16, 3.18... doesn't work.
I checked my grub configuration and my blacklist, nothing seems wrong.

I'm now trying to install Netrunner Rolling edition...

In the mean time, any idea why this isn't working?